# How does handling a lightsaber (weight and momentum) compare with an equal-sized sword?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, lightsaber

Potentially the balance of a lightsaber is very different from that of a sword. With a sword, the weight and momentum of the blade significantly affect the depth of the cut.

When the lightsaber is active, does the weight increase?  Or is swinging it just like swinging the handle?  Perhaps like swinging a Wii controller.

Comment: It's much lighter (pun partially intended).

Comment: There are lots of different questions here...

Comment: [Everything you always wanted to know about lightsabers but were afraid to ask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIefj6dOhnM)

Comment: If the blade is made from photons, then the mass will not increase when it's active (unless a Jedi/Sith does that with the force). But since we don't have actual lightsabers it's difficult to know how they function. However, the [third law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics) would seem to require (assuming it holds in a galaxy far far away) that the mass should decrease (assuming off is the minimal energy state).

Comment: Okay, I'll split it.